# Cordova app with inapp browser on external webview page

Tags: cordova, browser

I have built a few apps using cordova where I buld the homepage in the app, but then it links to pages on a webserver that mimic the look of the app.  This way I can update pages without having to resubmit the app to a store.  I have used the inapp browser on external links so they don't take over the app.

I have not built an app in a couple years, and when I went to make an app I found that this is not working any longer.  I am not sure if I am just forgetting something, or if something has changed in the last year or so.  What makes me think something has changed is that it is not working in ios or android.

I have a homepage, and any external links that I use the inapp browser work fine.   When I go to another page that is loaded in webview, I cannot get the inapp browser to work.   I remember an issue being the cordova.js file being loaded, but I have made sure those are available.

You can see a page here for ios:

http://vjcdesigns.com/clients/shiawassee/app/park.php

I cannot get that first link to work at all

`<a onClick="window.open('http://www.shiawassee.net/County-Parks/','_blank', 'EnableViewPortScale=yes');" data-ajax="false" href="#" data-role="button" >Parks Website</a>`

Then the park links the pdfs will not load, but the google map link will load in the system browser which is fine, the system browser or the inapp browser would be ok.

I have tried  _blank, _system, _self, but I cannot get the inapp browser to function.

For android I am having the same issue.  The initial index can use the inapp browser no problem, but once i link to an external page it is no longer working:

http://vjcdesigns.com/clients/shiawassee/park.php

I am not as worried about getting stuck in android since there is a back button, but for linking to pdfs I like to open the system browser.

I am using a mac, command line to create the apps, then using the current versions of xcode and android studio.

Does anyone have any ideas I can try, am I forgetting something, or did something change in the last year or so?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the plugins folder also needs to be uploaded to the server.